# Diabetic Retinopathy Detection CNN always guesses same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on building a CNN that detects Diabetic Retinopathy (DR) using a Dataset provided by Kaggle.com. The dataset consists of roughly 35000 Images with a minimum resolution of 2500x1900 and for each image there is a label from 0 to 4 attached which describes the severity of DR (0 being none detected and 4 being proliferate DR).

The past few days, I have been stuck on a problem regarding the predictions of my system. It appears that instead of picking up on important features in the images, the system consistently picks the value 0 (No DR) . At first, I thought this could be fixed by implementing balanced weights (the label 0 is overrepresented in the data) which did not change the outcome.

Furthermore, I have implemented augmentation of the data in the form of centralizing of the eye and feature extraction using cv2 and GaussianBlur which is illustrated by the picture below:

[image: 1]

This is done along with a resizing of the images to 400x400. During the data preprocessing the images are converted from jpeg format to a .npy file and saved as a numpy array. Also the labels are converted from a csv file to a .npy file.

Additionally, I attempted to fix this by combining the categories: 1, 2, 3, 4 into two categories yet this did not help either.

Even after all this data preprocessing and appliance of weights, it appears that after these implementations the system continues to predict that each image falls within label 0 (no DR detected). My current hunch is that the problem lies with feeding the training data to the system but other than that I feel pretty lost.

Below is the full script containing our model that receives the preprocessed images:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import keras
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.callbacks import History

history = History()


# Importing datasets.
DS_x_1 = np.load('C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documents/Intelligente systemer eksamensprojekt/Dataset/400x400/train400_x_0.npy', allow_pickle=True) 
DS_x_2 = np.load('C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documents/Intelligente systemer eksamensprojekt/Dataset/400x400/train400_x_1.npy', allow_pickle=True) 
DS_x_3 = np.load('C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documents/Intelligente systemer eksamensprojekt/Dataset/400x400/train400_x_2.npy', allow_pickle=True)
DS_x_4 = np.load('C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documents/Intelligente systemer eksamensprojekt/Dataset/400x400/train400_x_3.npy', allow_pickle=True) 
DS_y = np.load('C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documents/Intelligente systemer eksamensprojekt/Dataset/400x400/train400_y.npy', allow_pickle=True)[:8000]


#%%


print("loaded")

DS_x = np.concatenate((DS_x_1, DS_x_2, DS_x_3,DS_x_4), axis=0)
del DS_x_1
del DS_x_2
del DS_x_3
del DS_x_4

DS_x = DS_x.reshape(8000, 400, 400, 1)

print("concatenated")

# for label in range(len(DS_y)):
#     if DS_y[label] == 0:
#         pass
#     elif DS_y[label] == 2 or DS_y[label] == 1:
#         DS_y[label] = 1
#     else:
#         DS_y[label] = 2

DS_y_oneHot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(DS_y)

#%%


# Building our CNN model.
visible = Input(shape=(400,400,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(visible)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(conv3)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(pool4)
pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(conv5)
flat = Flatten()(pool5)
hidden1 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)


opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
lossf = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

# Compiling model.
hist = model.compile(optimizer = opt, 
              loss=lossf,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#%%

# Model summary.
model.summary()

#%%

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight("balanced", np.unique(DS_y),DS_y)

class_weights_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
print(class_weights_dict)

#%%

hist = model.fit(DS_x, DS_y_oneHot, validation_split=0.25, batch_size = 16, epochs=10, class_weight=class_weights_dict)

#%%

y_new = model.predict(DS_x[:100])

for i in range(100):
    print(y_new[i])
    print(DS_y[i])
```

I have searched the internet for solutions and I have currently tried three different network structures and changing the variables herein, all to no avail.

Any help/ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED:
Here is the model summary and system predictions:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: please add `model.summary()` result and output of calling `.fit()` (loss/accuracy dynamics)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the post has been updated! There might be discrepancies with the code describing the model and the model.summary(), but the newest version is the model.summary image